# Customize UIView to Look like an UIAlert

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create `UIView` that have to be displayed on top of all other content and have the background dim effect (parent view get darker).
I tried with:

```
BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(0f,0.5f);
```

but didn't worked.

please tell me what am i missing?

Comment: Can you show us the context of that line of code?

Comment: I know nothing of xamarin and care still less, but you will find this much easier if you start with example code that does what you're describing, and here it is: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: this is xcode's project and not xamarin's project